# AES Encryption losing end of XSL file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, aes, rsa, mongoid

I'm trying to use AES encryption in order to encrypt files that are being saved on MongoDB.
This uses the GridFS gem.

The AES key is being encrypted itself by RSA and then stored alongside the document within Mongo.

I was previously using `Mongoid::EncryptedFields.cipher.encrypt` which worked fine, however, the client wanted RSA keys to be used.

My xsl_action:

```
tempFile = params[:stylesheet].tempfile
file = File.open(tempFile)

grid_fs = Mongoid::GridFS

#Encryption
pub_file = CaseCenter::Config::Reader.get('pub_key');
public_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(pub_file))
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
key = cipher.random_key
encData = cipher.update(File.read(file))
#End Encryption

File.open(file, 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(encData)
end
encrypted_aes = Base64.encode64(public_key.public_encrypt(key))
stylesheet.aes_key = encrypted_aes

grid_file = grid_fs.put(file.path)
stylesheet.stylesheet_id = grid_file.id
```

To decrypt the file, I use this:

```
grid_fs = Mongoid::GridFs
f = grid_fs.get(stylesheet_id)

#Decryption
key = CaseCenter::Config::Reader.get('priv_key')
passphrase = CaseCenter::Config::Reader.get('key_pass')
if key.include? "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
  private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key,passphrase)
else
  private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(key),passphrase)
end
decKey = private_key.private_decrypt(Base64.decode64(doc[:aes_key]))
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = decKey
decData = cipher.update(f.data)
```

The AES key and file are properly encrypted, however, on decryption, the file loses the last 30 characters.
Am I doing something wrong during encryption?

EDIT 1:
Thought it could have been that I hadn't included cipher.final.

I have now included

```
encData << cipher.final
```

I am still having the same issue, not all of the file is being returned, however, there are less missing characters now. 
I now assume this issue is due to the initial encryption stage.

Comment: Separate storage and encryption and figure out which is the problem. Verify the data you store in gridfs is retrieved back completely, separately verify that your decryption works correctly.

Comment: @D.SM I've confirmed that the data stored in gridfs is retrieved back completely. 

I have been able to do this type of encryption/decryption on image files, but I'm running into this issue for XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might experience the same issue, I had forgotten to include cipher.final on both encryption and decryption.

```
#Encryption
encData << cipher.final

#Decryption
decData << cipher.final
```

This solved my issue.